# How do I get the output of an external command in Perl?

Tags: perl, command-line, batch-file

I want to have output of Windows command-line program (say, `powercfg -l`) written into a file which is created using Perl and then read the file line by line in a for loop and assign it to a string.

Comment: Please update your question with all the details you have in the comments to the answers so that people can help you better.  Error messages that you are getting and an example of what you are working with will help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
my $output = qx(powercfg -l);

## You've got your output loaded into the $output variable. 
## Still want to write it to a file?
open my $OUTPUT, '>', 'output.txt' or die "Couldn't open output.txt: $!\n";
print $OUTPUT $output;
close $OUTPUT

## Now you can loop through each line and
##   parse the $line variable to extract the info you are looking for.
foreach my $line (split /[\r\n]+/, $output) {
  ## Regular expression magic to grab what you want
}
```

Answer (score 29):

You have some good answers already. In addition, if you just want to process a command's output and don't need to send that output directly to a file, you can establish a pipe between the command and your Perl script.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $fh, '-|', 'powercfg -l') or die $!;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    # Do stuff with each $line.
}
```

Comment: There is no need for the defined test when reading from a file handle in a while statement. See the output of `perl -MO=Deparse -e "print while <>"`

Comment: @Sinan Thanks a lot. I was not familiar with `-MO=Deparse`. Very useful.

Comment: This is nice in that my $var=`command` can get out of hand if command happens to produce an outrageous amount of output and you start swapping. Not typical but it happens.

Answer (score 25):

```
system 'powercfg', '-l';
```

is the recommended way. If you don't mind spawning a subshell,

```
system "powercfg -l";
```

will work, too. And if you want the results in a string:

```
my $str = `powercfg -l`;
```

Comment: Don't forget to check the return value from the system call.

Comment: @craig: Is there a way to check the return value AND capture the output in a string?

Comment: Use backticks and check $? afterwards.

Comment: If you want to capture the output without spawning a subshell: `open my $pipe, '-|', qw(powercfg -l) or die; my @output = <$pipe>; close $pipe;`

Comment: open '-|' also spawns a subshell

Comment: Hi,
How to capture the command result in a string??
The above mentioned are not working!! 
Please suggest some other way to get this done ?

Comment: Why are they not working? What's the error message? What is the output of `$str=\`powercfg -l\`; print "Return code: $?\n"; print $str,"\n";` ?

Comment: Hi ppl....

I still cant assign the command output to a string: consider the follwing Perl PROGRAM in VIsta where i've used the DOS command -

my $str=sytem "powercfg -l";
print $str

OUTPUT::

%%% Output of the DOS command %%% 
0

here the value of the string $str is printed as 0.......
What do i do ???

Comment: notice this should be applied to Windows, it does not fully respect standards for opening anonymous pipe between parent and child. then usually command like  open PIPE,'-|' without command that makes implict fork, usually it does not work. This will work on linux or fully unix like systems.

Comment: `system "powercfg -l"` will not spawn a subshell in current versions of Perl, and I believe this was also the case in 2009 when the answer was written, and long before.

Answer (score 9):

There is no need to first save the output of the command in a file:

```
my $output = `powercfg -l`;
```

See `qx//` in [Quote-Like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators).

However, if you do want to first save the output in a file, then you can use:

```
my $output_file = 'output.txt';

system "powercfg -l > $output_file";

open my $fh, '<', $output_file 
    or die "Cannot open '$output_file' for reading: $!";

while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    # process lines
}

close $fh;
```

See [perldoc -f system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).

Answer (score 2):

Since the OP is running `powercfg`, s/he are probably capturing the ouput of the external script, so s/he probably won't find this answer terribly useful.  This post is primarily is written for other people who find the answers here by searching.

This answer describes several ways to start command that will run in the background without blocking further execution of your script.

Take a look at the [perlport entry for `system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#system).  You can use `system( 1, 'command line to run');` to spawn a child process and continue your script.

This is really very handy, but there is one serious caveat that is **not** documented. If you start more 64 processes in one execution of the script, your attempts to run additional programs will fail.

I have verified this to be the case with Windows XP and ActivePerl 5.6 and 5.8. I have not tested this with Vista or with Stawberry Perl, or any version of 5.10.

Here's a one liner you can use to test your perl for this problem:

```
C:\>perl -e "for (1..100) { print qq'\n $_\n-------\n'; system( 1, 'echo worked' ), sleep 1 }
```

If the problem exists on your system, and you will be starting many programs, you can use the [Win32::Process](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::Process) module to manage your application startup.

Here's an example of using `Win32::Process`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::Process;

if( my $pid = start_foo_bar_baz() ) {
    print "Started with $pid";
}
:w

sub start_foo_bar_baz {

    my $process_object;  # Call to Create will populate this value.
    my $command = 'C:/foo/bar/baz.exe';  # FULL PATH to executable.
    my $command_line = join ' ',
           'baz',   # Name of executable as would appear on command line
           'arg1',  # other args
           'arg2';

    # iflags - controls whether process will inherit parent handles, console, etc.
    my $inherit_flags = DETACHED_PROCESS;  

    # cflags - Process creation flags.
    my $creation_flags = NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS;

    # Path of process working directory
    my $working_directory = 'C:/Foo/Bar';

    my $ok = Win32::Process::Create(
       $process_object,
       $command,
       $command_line,
       $inherit_flags,
       $creation_flags, 
       $working_directory,
    );

    my $pid;
    if ( $ok ) {
        $pid = $wpc->GetProcessID;
    }
    else {
        warn "Unable to create process: "
             . Win32::FormatMessage( Win32::GetLastError() ) 
        ;
        return;
    }

    return $pid;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Sinan's excellent answer and to more explicitly answer your question:

NOTE: backticks `` tell Perl to execute a command and retrieve its output:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;


my @output = `powercfg -l`;
chomp(@output); # removes newlines

my $linecounter = 0;    
my $combined_line;

foreach my $line(@output){
    print $linecounter++.")";
    print $line."\n"; #prints line by line

    $combined_line .= $line; # build a single string with all lines
    # The line above is the same as writing:
    # $combined_line = $combined_line.$line;
}

print "\n";
print "This is all on one line:\n";
print ">".$combined_line."<";
```

Your output (on my system) would be:

```
0)
1)Existing Power Schemes (* Active)
2)-----------------------------------
3)Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced) *
4)Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (High performance)
5)Power Scheme GUID: a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a  (Power saver)

This is all on one line:
>Existing Power Schemes (* Active)-----------------------------------Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced) *Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (High performance)Power Scheme GUID: a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a  (Power saver)<
```

Perl makes it easy!

Answer (score 1):

Try using > operator to forward the output to a file, like:

```
powercfg -l > output.txt
```

And then open output.txt and process it.

Comment: Hi I want to use Perl in this.... as i don't know how to capture the output in a file (to be created) and read that file line by line and assigning the line to a string in the PERL script.