# How can I capture the output of pkgrm in Perl?

Tags: perl

I want to uninstall a package in Solaris, say `NewPackage`. For that I am using the command:

```
pkgrm NewPackage
```

It will display all the steps in the STDOUT and at the end it will give the message that the package is uninstalled successfully.

If i want to uninstall the same package in a Perl program how do I redirect the STDOUT messages to a file so that at the end of the execution I can go to the file and verify the file. Presently i tried the following commands without success:

```
open (FD, "/usr/tmp/result.txt");
$input1 = <FD>;
$input2 = <FD>;
system("pkgrm NewPackage" < $input1);
```

But don't know how to pass the second input.

Please advice how to proceed.

Comment: If you want to redirect the output of pkgrm to a file, then why are you trying the exact opposite in your example code?

Comment: i want to pass the input to the script in runtime and then redirect the output of pkgrm to another file for verification purposes

Answer (score 2):

In general:

- use the `strict` and `warnings` pragmas
- use 3 argument open with a lexical handle
- test to see if your open call succeeds before continuing your script
- if you are numbering your variable names (`$input1, $input2`) use an array instead (`@inputs`)
- if you want to use a variable name as a variable, use a hash instead
- when in doubt, [RTFM](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).  Since TFM is big and hard to find things in at first, you might want to read [How To RTFM](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=78752)
- [The FAQs](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-faq.html) are pretty handy too.  There's [a whole section on system interaction](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html), and [another on file manipulation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html).
- when you need a function to do some random task, look at the [functions by category section](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-functions-by-cat.html) in perlfunc.

No matter what, you will need to define what you are trying to do a little more specifically.

Do you want to run your command and dump its STDOUT to a file:

```
`pkgrm $package > $outfile`;
```

Or maybe append the results to an existing log:

```
`pkgrm $package >> $outfile`;
```

Or do you want to catch the results and see what happened in your program:

```
open( my $result_fh, '>', $outfile ) or die "can't open logfile - $!\n";
my $output = `pkgrm $package`;
if( $oupt =~ /happiness/) {
   print $result_fh "hooray!\n", $output;
}
else {

   print $result_fh "uh oh\n", $output;
}
```

Or do you need to monitor standard error?

Or should STDERR and STDOUT be combined into one stream?

For these cases and more [see perlfaq8](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command?).

Answer (score 0):

Your question has the same answer as [How do I get the output of an external command in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477500/how-do-i-get-the-output-of-an-external-command-in-perl).