# Find available space in /tmp on a remote machine

Tags: perl, bash, shell, ssh

I want to find out the available space in /tmp on a remote machine. I can do it with the following command from my machine:

```
ssh host-name df /tmp |  awk '{ print $4 }' | tail +2`
```

IT works and gives an output something like this :9076656, which the available space in KB.

But when I put this command inside a perl program, I get the error message about the use of uninitialized value for $4.

> Use of uninitialized value $4 in concatenation

Here is how I am doing  it in the perl code:

```
my $output = `ssh $server df /tmp |  awk '{ print $4 }' | tail +2`;
```

Any ideas how can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Funny how this is 'off-topic' when it exhibits a programming problem, would warrant a some comments on string interpolation in a programming language, and has received a programming solution.  I guess the Perl tag is just so darned flooded with questions that you guys have been required to have itchy close-fingers, eh?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `$4` is interpolated by Perl, just like you expect `$server` to be interpolated and not literal. The immediate solution is to escape the dollar sign: `\$4`. However, it is as Brian Agnew says, pretty redundant to use awk inside perl to do something that perl excels at.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @output = `ssh $server df /tmp`;      # capture output in array
@output = map { ( split )[3] } @output;  # take only 4th field
print Dumper \@output;                   # display data
```

Then you can use the various array tools to trim `@output` to your liking, e.g. pop, push, shift, unshift, splice, using slices and subscripts. For example, taking all but the first two lines:

```
print @output[2 .. $#output];
```

Removing the first two lines:

```
splice @output, 0, 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl to spawn off an awk script seems a little redundant (and heavyweight) given Perl's ability to read files, parse out fields etc. I would rather [investigate reading a process' output via Perl and splitting the output lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477500/how-do-i-get-the-output-of-an-external-command-in-perl).