# perl - return value from python

Tags: perl

I'm running a perl script that runs a python script.

```
# python code = run_me.py

def main():
    return 123;

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and the perl code:

```
# perl code
my $ret = // What should I write here?
print "ret = $ret" # should print "ret = 123"
```

system("run_me.py") --> returns exit code (in this case 0)

`run_me.py` --> returns the stdout (in this case empty string)

How do I get the 123 back to the perl without opening sockets or files? Is that possible?

Comment: Do you mean the POSIX return code, or are you expecting some textual output? If the former, you need to adjust your Python code to use `sys.exit()` and use [`system()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system) on the Perl side to capture it.

Comment: @tadman What if it's the latter one? returns some string?

Comment: Lots of [answers for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477500/how-do-i-get-the-output-of-an-external-command-in-perl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python program doesn't currently output anything.<sup>[1]</sup>

It looks like you are trying to set the exit code. To set the exit code, use `sys.exit`.

```py
import sys

def main():
    sys.exit(123)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

or

```py
import sys

def main():
    return 123

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

---

1. Technically, you could say it outputs an empty stream to stdout, an empty stream to stderr, and an exit code of zero. But it definitely doesn't output 123 in any way.

Comment: The thing is that the python code is already built and set up and being used by other python programs that use it as return values... Is there no other way to do it?

Comment: If you don't actually return a return code, your code isn't working properly anyway. The return value from `main()` is thrown in the trash in your code. You might want `sys.exit(main())` in your last line to do something with that return value.

Comment: Re "*Is there no other way to do it?*", There are other ways in which the program could be modified, but it currently doesn't output anything. So if you want it to output something, you will need to modify it. (Or use it as part of a larger Python program as the other answer proposes.)

Answer (score 4):

The Python program is written incorrectly for what you want to do with it.  You want the 123 to be communicated from the Python process into some other process.  But Python's `return` does not perform interprocess communication.  (Hence ikegami's suggestion of `sys.exit()`, which *is* an interprocess communication mechanism.)  The best solution is to fix the Python script:

```py
        # run_me.py
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            print(main())
```

Then some other process, such as one running Perl, can read the output of the `main` function from a pipe:

```perl
        # perl
        my $result = qx{ run_me.py };
```

If for some reason it is impossible for you to modify the Python program, you can still get it to do what you want, but it will be a hack, because it has to work around the misdesign of the original Python program.  In Perl, try:

```perl
        # perl
        my $result = qx{ python -c 'import run_me; print(run_me.main())' };
```

I would prefer to use a pipe rather than `exit` because it is more general and less subject to obscure limitations.  But if you did really want to use `exit` the same hack would work for exfiltrating the 123 from the Python process:

```perl
        # perl
        system "python -c 'import run_me; exit(run_me.main())' ";
        my $result = $? >> 8 ;
```